# Parameter Estimation of coin that is tossed 10 times

Tags: statistics

A coin is tossed 10 times, with the results: H T T H H T H H H T. What is the
maximum-likelihood estimate of its bias? If you want to make a Bayesian estimate of
its parameter, how does the estimate change with every toss, starting from a prior
of Beta(1,1)?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a free [homework/tutorial service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). You're going to get a lot more positive response if you show your own efforts. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? You need to ask a more *specific* question other than "can somebody do all the work for me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to solve your homework for you but here are some points to get you started. You don't specify any coding language (Stack Overflow deals with *coding*-specific questions), so I'm using R here.

Tossing a coin is a binomial process, with two outcomes (heads "H" and tails "T") and a single parameter `theta = p` as the probability of the coin coming up with "H".

The sample data consists of 10 coin tosses

```r
x <- unlist(strsplit("H T T H H T H H H T", " "))
```

1. It is straight-forward (and a good exercise) to calculate the MLE estimate for the parameter `p` by hand. You will find that the MLE for `p` is simply `(number of "H"s) / (total number of coin tosses)`. In your case, this gives

   ```r
   mle_est_binom <- function(x) sum(x == "H") / length(x)
   mle_est_binom(x)
   #[1] 0.6
   ```
2. We can also use base R's function `optim` to optimise the binomial likelihood function as a function of `p`, given the observed data. Since `optim` by default performs minimisation, maximising the positive likelihood function translates to minimising the *negative* likelihood function.

   ```r
   lik <- function(p) -dbinom(sum(x == "H"), length(x), p)
   mle_est <- optim(0.5, lik, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0, upper = 1)
   mle_est$par
   #[1] 0.5999997
   ```

   The `optim`-based ML estimate for `p` agrees very well with the previous "exact" MLE value.

   Here we maximise the (linear) likelihood function. It is often advantageous to maximise the *log-transformed* likelihood function (think about *why* that would be the case). `dbinom` directly returns the log-transformed likelihood if you use function argument `log = TRUE`. Rewriting the optimisation step using the log-transformed likelihood is a good check and helps to wrap your head around how `optim` works.
3. I will leave you with the Bayesian estimation. You can find plenty of tutorials on the web on how to do that in R. Personally, I recommend using `rstan`.

---

PS. There exists an interesting [article written by Andrew Gelman and Deborah Nolan: *You Can Load a Die, But You Can’t Bias a Coin*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf), that elaborates on the subject of biased coins. It's a nice and fun article showing that

> it is not possible to bias a coin flip — that is, one cannot, for example, weight a coin so that it is substantially more likely to land “heads” than “tails” when  flipped and caught in the hand in the usual manner.